# Adjust mysql query to filter out today from the date

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi all i currently have this sql:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*
      FROM articles a
      WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND a.active = 1
      ORDER BY views ASC
     ) a
ORDER BY views ASC
```

It lists all articles posted in the last week, what I want to do is adjust it so it ignored today, is that easy to do?

Comment: Why not try first and post the SQL if you are having difficulties? Why ask ahead of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. You just need to add `AND date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())`

For simplicity, you can use the `BETWEEN` operator:

```
WHERE `date` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY))
                       AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

I believe this allows the engine to make better use of indexes than individual `>=` and `<=` calls, but I'm not certain on that.

Comment: That's fantastic, didn't realise you could do that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
SELECT `a`.*
FROM `articles` AS a
WHERE `date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(TODAY() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND `date` <= UNIXTIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) `a`.`active` = 1
ORDER BY `views` ASC
```

Suffice for this task?

Comment: Probably not, unless all articles are published precisely at midnight.

Comment: I see what you mean and I've changed my answer accordingly, not that it really matters since it's doest exactly what yours suggest (except using the BETWEEN function).